# ATtiny45, Arduino programming error?

Tags: ide, arduino, microcontroller

I set up my Arduino and [ATtiny45](http://www.atmel.com/devices/attiny45.aspx) the way the tutorial *[How-To: Shrinkify Your Arduino Projects](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30rPt802n1k)* showed. I wish to make an LED, hooked up to my breadboard, blink.

I'm running Windows XP, and I have the latest release of the Arduino IDE and have set up my programmer to be Arduino as ISP, as well as my board to be ATtiny45 (8 MHz internal clock).

The problem occurs when I try and upload the compiled code onto the board. The IDE returns this error:

> avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

I have searched for answers for a long time, but I found nothing. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It means that your microcontroller is not detected. Things to check:

1. Wiring: are the pins used for chip programming correctly connected (no crossing?)
2. Power supply: Is the board properly powered?
3. PC configuration: Is the Arduino IDE using the correct port of the PC?

and from [the Arduino help](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/help.html):

1. If you have an [Arduino NG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_compatibles#Arduino_NG), did you press reset just before selecting
   Upload menu item?
2. Is the correct serial port selected?
3. Is the correct driver installed?
4. Is the chip inserted into the Arduino properly?
5. If you built your own Arduino or have burned the bootloader on yourself: Does the chip have the correct bootloader on it?

Arduino is bootloader based. This means that the chip must have a little piece of software inside that is responsible for the communication with the Arduino IDE and the self programming of your application binary into the chip. This piece of software is called "bootloader". If your chip came empty ( sold separately or erased by mistake ), there is no bootloader inside.

There is no way to program a booloader into a chip without using an external programmer.
(Or another bootloader already inside. Some chips include a low level bootloader in the ROM...)
But, luckily for you, building a home made programmer for AtTiny is easy. Search google for "AtTyny ISP programmer".

And if you have questions about that, ask them at "Electrical Engineering StackExchange"

Comment: The pins are wired and connected right. The board is properly powered. How can I check that what the right port has to be?
Why must I press the reset button before uploading?
The correct driver is installed. The chip is inserted well onto the breadboard. I did not build the Arduino myself, nor did I burn the bootloader.

Comment: Also, how can I check that the AT Tiny 45 works if I cannot make it work with my Arduino?

Comment: You have to reset the board in order to call the bootloader. If the MCU is running your code at this time, it won't work. The AT Tiny 45 was shipped with the arduino board or is it a new and completely empty part ?

Comment: It was shipped separately. When exactly do I reset the board? I always press the button right before I click upload in my IDE but the thing is that it says it's compiling code and then after some time it says it's uploading it.

Comment: Ok, but the question is to know if the AtTiny 45 you are using was shipped with the Arduino bootloader inside or not.

Comment: Now it's clear. You first have to burn abootloader into the chip. see http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Bootloader?from=Main.Bootloader for the exact procedure. but you will have to use additional hardware for programming the chip.

Comment: There will never be any bootloader if you're trying to program with an external programmer.

Comment: not sure I have understood your reply. I say that  an Arduino bootloader is required  to program your software into the chip using the arduino IDE. If your chip is empty. It won't work. You first have to program the bootloader into the chip using an external programmer. And then you will have a system that will be recognized by the Arduino IDE.

Comment: When I try to upload the bootloader through the IDE, it returns the same error.

Comment: Maybe I should have started with this: Are you familiar with bootloaders? Do you know what they do ? And how they basically works ? I kindly ask you this because you can't program a bootloader into a chip without using a device programmer or another bootloader that is already in the chip. If your AtTyny came empty. There is nothing inside. There is NO WAY for you to program the bootloader using the Arduino IDE only. There is an option to do it in the IDE which is used to update the bootloader of a chip that ALREADY has a bootloader inside.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a virgin ATTiny, you need to set the fuse bits on it. **It does not require the Arduino bootloader**, but the process is similar to burning the bootloader. [This tutorial](http://hlt.media.mit.edu/?p=1695) helped me get my ATTiny85 up and running, take note of the "Configuring the ATtiny to run at 8 MHz (for SoftwareSerial support)" section.

Also, I've noticed there are different 'board drivers': the items that appear in 'Tools > Board' in the Arduino IDE. You may be using a set that does not work, try [this](https://github.com/damellis/attiny/tree/Arduino1), [this](http://hlt.media.mit.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/attiny45_85.zip) or have a google around to find more. Just be sure to go through the entire process when you try a new set (i.e. burn the bootloader, reboot, burn your code).

Good luck.

Comment: Excuse me, burning boot loader internally does the fuse work for you. It's all just wrapped up in arduino ide and you're not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had the same issue with Duemilenove Arduino compatible board i bought

I found this fix.

Go to \hardware\arduino\boards.txt, find this line "uno.name=Arduino Uno uno.upload.protocol=arduino", replace the protocol=arduino to =stk500.
I don't know if it works on Uno, but it did save me from similar issue with Duemilanove.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with getting attiny85 to work.
In my case, arduino micro was used to program it.
I digged into this problem and found that the recent version of arduino IDE(1.8.5) was slightly wrong with its configuration of utilizing the avrdude.
I'm assuming that you already tried burning bootloader but it fails with STK500 sync error.

How to fix:

1. Prepare a text editor program which is able to edit unix line ending files properly. eg) Vim, Emacs, Microsoft Visual Studio, notepad+, atom
2. Go to the arduino install directory. eg) C:\Program Files(x86)\Arduino
3. Open hardware\arduino\avr\programmers.txt with the editor you prepared. If it's under the program files directory, running text editor as administrator would be useful.
4. On line 44, you can find `Arduino as ISP`. Keep following those lines and edit these two lines like below.

   `arduinoasisp.protocol=arduino
   arduinoasisp.program.protocol=arduino`
5. Save and try burning bootloader again.

It must had `stk500v1` as default. It basically should be the same but the recent version of avrdude(also included in arduino ide by default) has different workflow on them.

Another useful info: burning bootloader on attiny also does fuse work.